pyqt6 and PostgreSQL for information managment task
i have created  smple  pyqt6 application, which looks like this :

so i have product database and i want to  write  a product from input panel  and  python should search product in database, for this one i have  added following line to pyqt6 application :
 def clickMethod(self):
        product =self.line.text()
        df = pd.read_sql_query('select * from "foreign_products"', con=engine)
        print(df.head())

here question is  how to  add product in  read_sql_quary commend? after  i bit research , i found following solution for strings :
df = pd.read_sql_query('''SELECT * FROM "Prices" where "Type" = 'Daily'
''', conn)

but what about  customer based string?based on my previous question, i got following solution :
curr.execute("""
    INSERT INTO message_sentiment(mytext,text_label,score)
    VALUES (%s, %s, %s);
    """,
    (text,label, score))

how can i combine this solution with my   task? thanks  in advance
